# Concatenate 2 circular double linked list without using extra pointer

Tags: pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I have 2 circular double linked list with head nodes as h1 and h2. I need to append h2 at the end of h1.
However I am unable to do it without use of an extra pointer. I believe it is impossible to do  so without using any extra pointer as we will always lose the address of the last node of either of the list (unless we traverse to the very end which cannot be done without an extra pointer).
Any clue how if possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without introducing a variable to hold a temporary pointer?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, problem constraints.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for *practical* programming questions. There is a whole 'nother site dedicated to programming puzzles, [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is "a practical programming question", I want to reduce the overhead costs of traversing the double circular linked list or using extra space.

Comment: Saving 1 register is rarely a practical programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the lists are *circular* you can find the tail of both trivially.  So to append you just need two temporary pointers (t1 and t2), and the procedure is (assuming neither list is empty):

```
  t1       = h1->prev ;
  t2       = h2->prev ;
  h1->prev = t2 ;
  t1->next = h2 ;
  h2->prev = t1 ;
  t2->next = h1 ;
```

You can do it with no temporary pointers:

```
  h1->prev->next = h2 ;               // t1->next = h2
  h2->prev->next = h1 ;               // t2->next = h1
  h2             = h1->prev ;
  h1->prev       = h2->next->prev ;   // h1->prev = t2
  h2->next->prev = h2 ;               // h2->prev = t1
```

But this is (a) more work and (b) obscure.  So, unless you have a processor which is terrifyingly short of registers, this has absolutely nothing to recommend it.  A half way decent compiler may optimise out some of this nonsense... but may well not come up with the simplest possible code (ie, not spot that *two* temporary pointers simplify things.)